CSV mongoimiport with merge option not updating existing data
I have an requirement to update existing mongo db document after reading some relevant data from hdfs saved as csv
Steps I am taking care of

Created a view on mongo collection to convert _id to it since csv import does not include id field default with mongoexport json type

filtered data with step 1 csv and hdfs and saved required data to csv

Using mongoimport utility to merge csv data to update exsiting document for each id field
Issue:
It's always insert a new document and not updating the existing data with id filed


Is there anyway to import csv data as is and update the existing document for each id available in  csv
I have workaround to convert this csv data to json array to convert id to
{
"_id": {
"$oid": "665fe3d07749dc8c8085ed32"
},
but bit concerning since have huge data to apply such transformation and the converted json size is way high then csv data
It's always insert a new document and not updating the existing data with id filed
Is there anyway to import csv data as is and update the existing document for each id available in  csv
I have workaround to convert this csv data to json array to convert id to
{
"_id": {
"$oid": "665fe3d07749dc8c8085ed32"
},
but bit concerning since have huge data to apply such transformation and the converted json size is way high then csv data

How about using mongoimport to import your raw csv first and then use aggregation pipeline to wrangle your data and $merge to update the data?

@ray, Thanks for your comment , I am new to mogodb so,I haven't use it , Could you please help to share some reference if any

That is a rather broad solution, instead of a specific programming question, thus does not fit in a StackOverflow post. You need to provide a [mre] to give be more specific and give more context.
